# Counting how many times each unique element appeared in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table called `key_uniqueWord`. This is how it looks like.

[image]

This is how the table is created..

```
CREATE TABLE `key_uniqueword` (
 `p_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `word` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `uniqueWordCount` int(11) NOT NULL,
 KEY `conv4` (`uniqueWordCount`,`p_id`,`word`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I can get the list of each unique individual record in `word` column from the following command.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `word` from `key_uniqueword`
```

I can check how many times a "particular" individual element in `word` column appeared in the `key_uniqueword` table by using the below command. For an example, lets check for the word "about"

```
SELECT COUNT(`word`) FROM `key_uniqueword` WHERE `word`="about"
```

Just like this, I need to know how many times "each" unique element in `word` column appears in the `key_uniquword` table. I am expecting the output to be like the below table structure. It has 2 columns, **word** and **count**

```
word   |   count
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
about  |   99,450
a      |   1000
talk   |   7980
men    |   20,915
```

How can I do this in a MySQL query?
**Important**
Please note that `p_id` not same for every row.

Comment: p_id is the same for all rows? Your table has no PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: @Strawberry: No, it is not.

Comment: @Strawberry: Yes, it has no primary key.

Comment: What kind of data do you store in the column `uniqueWordCount`? It seems that you don't have to compute count if you already know count.

Comment: @ntalbs: Imagine it as just a random number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct query is:

SELECT COUNT(`word`) AS count FROM `key_uniqueword` group by `word`

Answer (score 2):

```
select word, count(*) as count
from key_uniqueword
group by word
```

Comment: Hi, shouldn't it be count(word) instead of count(*)?

Answer (score 1):

```
select word, count(1)
from key_uniqueword
group by word;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT word, count(*) as occurance FROM key_uniqueword GROUP BY word;
```

IMHO, if you are having third column where you store word count then it will be a very weak database design and will cause redundancy/duplication, my point is `count` in your case is a derived attribute. You shouldn't waste you storage for this.

In some cases its good to keep derived attributes in your database to speed up your queries but I think you don't need it here.

Comment: Hi, shouldn't it be `count(word)` instead of `count(*)`?